# JPA many to many association with join table having index column create new primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

currently we are facing this critical issue in our project and not sure how to configure JPA to meet our desired need

We have 5 tables in our database with below relationship

```
A
Id

B
Id

C
Id

A_B
Id A_Id B_Id

D
Id A_B_Id C_Id
```

**Enity A**

```
@Entity
Class A{

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_Id", referencedColumnName = "Id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_Id", referencedColumnName = "Id"))
    private List<B> bList;
}
```

Now when I try to save entity A, due to storing B in List(we can't change to Set) it first delete all the records from A_B and then reinsert. That is not desirable as D has reference to A_B Id , so based on below article I added an index column in A_B and it solves the save problem

http://assarconsulting.blogspot.fr/2009/08/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-then-re.html

Now my A_B looks like

```
A_B
Id A-Id B_Id idx
```

and entity A as

```
@Entity
    Class A{

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_Id", referencedColumnName = "Id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_Id", referencedColumnName = "Id"))
        @OrderColumn(name = "idx")
        private List<B> bList;
    }
```

After doing this change, I am not able to deploy the code as JPA is throwing exception for entity C

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK76F831D84C8F0D59:D[A_B_Id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (A_B[A_Id,idx])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1714)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1637)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1355)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 45 more

Entity C is

    @Entity
    class C{

    @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "D", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "C_Id", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_B_Id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
        private List<A_B> a_bList;
    }
```

So here we are clueless how to save A without delete and also keeping D relationship intact. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a ManyToMany between A and B since

- the A_B table is mapped as an entity, so it can't also be mapped as a join table
- the A_B table has an ID column, which will never be populated by Hibernate if mapped as a join table

The same is true for the association between C and A_B, for the same reasons.

What you should have is

- A has a OneToMany with AB
- B has a OneToMany with AB
- D has a ManyToOne with AB
- D has a ManyToOne with C

of course, all of these associations can also be mapped in the other direction.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying but insertion is happening fine in join table. I just create an instance of A and populate B as a list. When I persist A, records are getting created with A and B Id in join table.

As AB is just a join table, so by this mapping I can directly access list of mapped B otherwise with your approach I need to loop AB list and get all the B's

Hope comment make sense to you

Comment: My point is that it populates A_ID and B_ID, but not ID. And since you want to map this table as an entity anyway, it should not be also mapped as a join table.

Comment: ID is auto incremental as of type identity so it will be automatically populated. You have a point that AB is used an entity in C so inside A we should use it as OneToMany rather than ManyToMany. But to solve delete problem, I anyway have to use index column and C also I have to use OneToMany with entity D. Is it really not possible through JPA to achieve what I need?